# netsh advfirewall can not set group profile

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, netsh

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, 64 bit. Powershell version 5.1.144049.

Trying to use a command from this [Microsoft Support Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh) -> Example 8: Enable specific services

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes profile=private
```

Returns with

> Only the enable parameter can be used to update rules specified by a group.

I need to change the profile of a group of rules, is there a way to do this programmatically or with a one liner?

Answer (score 0):

Omit `profile=private` and it works:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes
```

PowerShell one-liner:

```
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop" -Enabled True
```

Comment: `Set-NetFirewallRule` is only available for Server 2012+, I am on 2008 R2 std

Comment: @BenderBending Fair enough. I've updated the answer with the working `netsh` command.